# Determining the network connection link speed

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, networking

How do I programmatically determine the network connection link speed for an active network connection - like Task Manager shows you in the Networking tab? I'm not really after the bandwidth available, just a figure for the current connection, e.g. 54Mbps, 100Mbps etc.

Comment: What if the system has more than one adapter? There's no concept of a single "active network connection".

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849375/determine-network-interface-bandwidth-type-without-transferring-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I found the [`Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394340(VS.85).aspx) WMI class, as I need to support legacy platforms which, unfortunately, the `Win32_NetworkAdapter` doesn't do. `Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` has a `CurrentBandwidth` property which gives me what I need on all required platforms (I realise I said I didn't need "bandwidth" but its acceptable and appears to return the "nominal bandwidth" of the adapter anyway).

Thanks to all those who posted, pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

[`Win32_NetworkAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(VS.85,loband).aspx) WMI class can help you (`Speed` property). It returns the value 54000000 for my WiFi adapter connected to a WiFi-g access point.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the explanation of that property states, "This property has not been implemented yet. It returns a NULL value by default"?

Comment: You are right about MaxSpeed. I remember I have worked with the Speed property. I'm sure Speed works on Vista and Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

.NET way how to know adapter speed is

```
IPGlobalProperties computerProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
if ( nics != null )
    for (int i = 0; i < nics.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("Adapter '{0}' speed : {1}", nics[i].Name, nics[i].Speed);
```

Some adapters are tunnels, so their speed will be returned as 0.
Read [NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) documentation on the MSDN for more information.