# Get Link Speed - Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface

Tags: windows, perl, wmi, wmi-query

I found [Determining the network connection link speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849728/determining-the-network-connection-link-speed) 
and now I am trying to correlate the data from **Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface** with
**Win32_NetworkAdapter** (or **Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration**).

On the class `Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` I don't see any
index or unique key that I can use to reference
`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration` or `Win32_NetworkAdapter.
I tried to use the`Name`in`Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface
`and`Win32_NetworkAdapter`, but still they look different.

e.g.

> Name: Intel(R) PRO/1000 PL Network
>   Connection

vs

> Name: Intel[R] PRO_1000 PL Network
>   Connection

Any hints?

Thank you in advance,

Milde

===

Maybe that piece of code will help you to help me guys :)

```
# I got the DeviceID of a NIC and use it to get the "NetConnection ID":

$objWMIService = Win32::OLE->GetObject("winmgmts:\\\\$computer\\root\\CIMV2") or die "Exit: WMI connection failed. \n";
$colNicSetts = $objWMIService->ExecQuery(
              "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter Where DeviceID = '$ID'", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);

foreach my $objItem (in $colNicSetts){
    $NetConnID = $objItem->{NetConnectionID};    
}

# => $NetConnID stores "Intel(R) PRO/1000 PL Network Connection".
# Now I tried to get the Link Speed with sth. like that:

$collItems = $objWMIService->ExecQuery(
             "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface Where Name = '$NetConnID'", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately | wbemFlagForwardOnly);
foreach my $objItem (in $collItems){
    $LinkSpeed = $objItem->{CurrentBandwidth};
}
# "Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface" contains "Intel[R] PRO_1000 PL Network" Connection
# "Intel(R) PRO/1000 PL Network Connection" != Intel[R] PRO_1000 PL Network Connection
# => $LinkSpeed empty
```

Comment: Can you post a short Perl script that shows how you get the information? As it is, there is very little useful information in your post in terms of helping others who are not working on the same problem get started. You do not even tell us which adapter string is coming from which source etc. You could try normalizing the strings by converting all non-word characters to `_`, but that would be a last resort.

Comment: Added some code, hope it helps. I thought about wildcards too, but it seems a bit unsecure for me.

Comment: I believe, it's a little bit late... but there are some notes about naming convention at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.instancename(v=vs.110).aspx - "If the instance name is automatically generated and might contain the characters "(", ")", "#", "\", or "/", use the character mapping in the following table." However this won't help mapping crazy names like isatap.{GUID} or index suffixes.

Answer (score 4):

OK. Thanks for posting the short script. While you were working on that, I was following a different track using [DBD::WMI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD::WMI) and digging through the docs to see if you had missed anything.

I could not find a better way (there must be one) than canonicalizing the names:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;

my $computer = '.';
($computer) = @ARGV if @ARGV;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:WMI:$computer", undef, undef,
    { RaiseError => 1},
);

print "=== From Win32_NetworkAdapter ===\n";

my $name = $dbh->selectall_arrayref(
    'SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE DeviceID = 11'
)->[0]->[0]->{Name};

(my $canonname = $name) =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g;

print "Name: $name\nCanonical name: $canonname\n\n";

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface'
);

$sth->execute;

print "=== From Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface ===\n";

while (defined (my $adapter = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref )) {
    my $conf = $adapter->[0];
    my $perfname = $conf->{Name};
    (my $canonperfname = $perfname) =~ s/[^A-Za-z0-9]/_/g;
    if ( $canonperfname =~ /^$canonname/ ) {
        print "Name: $perfname\nCanonical name: $canonperfname\n";
        print $conf->{CurrentBandwidth}, "\n\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
=== From Win32_NetworkAdapter ===
Name: Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
Canonical name: Intel_R__PRO_Wireless_3945ABG_Network_Connection

=== From Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface ===
Name: Intel[R] PRO_Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection - Packet Scheduler Miniport
Canonical name: Intel_R__PRO_Wireless_3945ABG_Network_Connection___Packet_Scheduler_Miniport
54000000
```

Comment: @Milde I know, there **must** be a better way.

Comment: thank you Sinan. Your code will work as long as ($canonperfname =~ /^$canonname/) is true :) .
Unfortunately, I wont be able to use "DBD::WMI", but that's not the problem. This "simple" task drives me crazy...
Hoping for more suggestions.

Comment: @Milde Looking at the pages returned by http://www.google.com/search?q=Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface I see that this is a commonly recurring issue and *some* kind of canonicalization of the name seems to be the only solution. You could use some character that is unlikely to occur as part of the name such as `chr(254)` instead of `_` when canonicalizing and strip off the ` - Packet Scheduler Miniport` so that you can use `eq`.

Comment: The `DBD::WMI` part is not necessary. I just used it to get off the ground because I wanted to minimize the amount of docs I needed to lookup (your sample code was not available when I started working on this).

Comment: @Sinan: I recalculated your reputation, as requested.  It actually went up a few points!  Don't see that often. :)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Thanks. I had thought it would have gone down as well.

Comment: I tryed that as well but it only works for certain interfaces. Most of them doesn't seem to have a pattern, for istance I have *Intel[R] PRO_1000 MT Network Connection _2 - Network Load Balancing Filter Device* and *Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection*. I can't figure out a better solution however. This is driving me crazy...

Answer (score 3):

I just looked to my machine withe the WMI-Tools, because I thought, it must be easy ... ;-)
but it's not ...

But what I found on my machine was, the a concatenantion of the "Win32_NetworkAdapter.Name" + "  __" + "Win32_NetworkAdapter.InterfaceIndex" 
results in the "Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface.Name="NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller _2" [Regard the space too!].

Example from my machine:

```
Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID="13"
Win32_NetworkAdapter.NetConnectionID="Local Area Connection 2"
Win32_NetworkAdapter.InterfaceIndex="2"
Win32_NetworkAdapter.Name="NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller"
Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface="NVIDIA nForce Networking Controller _2"
```

I hope, I've understood your question right and this may help?!

br--mabra

Comment: This doesn't always work, as interfaceindex does not always match the Plug and Play device name

Answer (score 1):

The only approach I was able to find was to use the [Win32_PnPEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx) class to get the DeviceName for the network adapter, then convert it into the [InstanceName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.instancename(v=vs.110).aspx). This allows you to find a key value that you can use on other WMI tables (I used InterfaceIndex, but there are other choices in the [Win32_NetworkAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx) class.

So at a high level:

1. Get an instance of Win32_NetworkAdapter
2. Use one of the two below [WMI WQL queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394606(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the PnpEntity
3. Convert the Win32_PNPEntity.Name into the InstanceName by replacing:

   1. ( with [
   2. ) with ]
   3. # \ / all with _
4. Use that InstanceName to query the `Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` class

It is pretty convoluted, but since  InstanceName is derrived from the PnPEntity Name, that is the only way I could find to get accurate mappings.

Here are the two ways I was able to get the PnPEntity instance for a NetworkAdapter:

```
ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_NetworkAdapter.DeviceID='12'} WHERE ResultClass=Win32_PnPEntity

SELECT * FROM Win32_PNPEntity where DeviceID='PCI\\VEN_14E4&DEV_1684&SUBSYS_1309103C&REV_10\\4&11050A08&0&00E5'
```