# Powershell: Counter Instance Name for specific Network Card

Tags: powershell, wmi, performancecounter

I can get the network card counter instance names like so:

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface
```

Which outputs something like this for Name:

```
Intel[R] Ethernet Controller X540-AT2
Intel[R] Ethernet Controller X540-AT2 _2
Intel[R] Ethernet Controller X540-AT2 _3
Intel[R] Ethernet Controller X540-AT2 _4
```

I can get the (enabled) Network cards like so:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus=2"
```

which outputs something like this for Name:

```
Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X540-AT2
Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X540-AT2 #4
```

However there's no properties returned from either call that directly match the other.

The closest is win32_networkadapter's name, which is *similar* to the counter name, but has been altered to remove illegal characters and alter others(*1), and has some sort of instancing going on(*2).

(*1) = Just in testing, it swaps round brackets ("()") for the square brackets ("[]"), and escapes hashes for underscores.

(*2) = In a machine with four network adapters,

My question is: How do I directly map one for the other, without relying on my guesswork text replacement?

**Edit:**
If you're trying to test this on a VM, you'll need to add at least two network cards.

Here's the relevant output from a Windows Server 2012 R2 VM running on Hyper-V:

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | select Name

 Name
 ----
 Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
 Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter _2
 Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter _3


 Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus=2" | select Name

 Name
 ----
 Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #2
 Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter
 Microsoft Hyper-V Network Adapter #3
```

**Edit again:**

String replacement is right out, and just doesn't work on servers that are using NIC teaming.

Here's an example of a server that's using NIC teaming:

```
 Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus=2" | select name

 Name
 ----
 Intel(R) 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection
 Intel(R) 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection
 Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection
 Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection
 TEAM : PublicTeam
 TEAM : PrivateTeam


 Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | select Name


 Name
 ----
 TEAM : PrivateTeam - Intel[R] 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection
 TEAM : PublicTeam - Intel[R] 82575EB Gigabit Network Connection _2
 TEAM : PrivateTeam - Intel[R] 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection
 TEAM : PublicTeam - Intel[R] 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection _2
```

***Edit the third/fourth: ***

Yet another machine that doesn't even use the above somewhat guessable naming scheme.

This is on Windows Server 2012 R2:

```
 Get-WmiObject Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface | select Name

 Name
 ----
 Intel[R] 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection
 Intel[R] 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection _2
 Intel[R] 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection _3
 Intel[R] 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection _4

 Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -filter "netconnectionstatus=2" | select Name

 Name
 ----
 Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection
 Intel(R) 82576 Gigabit Dual Port Network Connection
 Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver
 Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver #2
```

Note that in this case, it's the Microsoft Network Adapter's that actually have IPs.

Although in this scenario, the matching performance counters on the *adapter* perf counters actually work (interface seems more reliable in other situations)

Edit 5:

People keep making comments like 
"It's similar to this other thread: [Get Link Speed - Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832586/get-link-speed-win32-perfrawdata-tcpip-networkinterface)"

As already explained in edits above, I give examples where this kind of text fudging doesn't work.

Comment: I dont think you can map `Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` to `win32_networkadapter` because there isnt a shared key..but you could relate to `networkadapterconfiguration`...it just depends on what properties of the nic you want to see....also which version of powershell are you using?

Comment: I need the actual performance counter name - how I get there doesn't matter, so long as I can map it back to ``win32_networkadapter`` (or the ``win32_networkadapterconfiguration``) - I'm using the information from that, to determine which perf counter relates to which network on the system (dmz, private, etc) - that perf counter instance name is then passed to another app. I don't see how the config table helps.

Comment: Not sure what OS you are using but on my Windows 10 machine & a win 2012 virtual machine both classes return matching names so i am afraid i cannot test this..

Comment: @Kiran You will need multiple network cards of the same type. On a WS2012 R2 hyper-v guest I added three network cards and see as per the edit.

Comment: Have you tried using `Get-Counter` and `Get-NetAdapter` instead ? Maybe you can match the interfaces easier then ? See `(Get-Counter -ListSet "Network Adapter").PathsWithInstances` for example for a list of network counters. WMI can be a pain sometimes ...

Comment: @sodawillow Those two don't really help much - same names are returned, and Get-Counter doesn't give any more useful information for matching one to the other.

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832586/get-link-speed-win32-perfrawdata-tcpip-networkinterface

Comment: @ST8Z6FR57ABE6A8RE9UF - only superficially - and they used string replacement (which, again, doesn't work in all scenarios)

Comment: Have you checked out the 'get-netadapter' and 'get-netadapterstatistics' cmdlets? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130889(v=wps.630).aspx .

I will say it's not perfect, but it's a lot more promising. 

The two cmdlets have the 'instanceid' and 'interfaceguid' which seem relatable, but my physical card doesn't have an entry in the 'get-netadapterstatistics'. I'll have to play around, but get-netadapter does at least indicate which NIC is physical and which is virtual (-HardwareInterface).

Comment: The following thread discusses this issue: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832586/get-link-speed-win32-perfrawdata-tcp ​ip-networkinterface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832586/get-link-speed-win32-perfrawdata-tcp%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bip-networkinterface)

Comment: @ConanW It does, as mentioned above. It's also using string replacement fudging, which doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Link Speed - Win32\_PerfRawData\_Tcpip\_NetworkInterface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832586/get-link-speed-win32-perfrawdata-tcpip-networkinterface)

Comment: @TravisEz13 You're now the third person to mention this other thread. I've explained in existing edits why this isn't applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the relation other than that name.

So as I can't imagine all the replacement caracters I instore a canonical name:

```
$cananicalName1 = "Intel(R) Ethernet Controller X540-AT2 #4" -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9]','_'
$cananicalName2 = "Intel[R] Ethernet Controller X540-AT2 _4" -replace '[^A-Za-z0-9]','_'
```

both gives :

```
Intel_R__Ethernet_Controller_X540_AT2__4
```

Comment: Unfortunately Text replacement doesn't help. I found a box where this won't work at all. I'll edit the question with more information.