# hresult from IMbnInterfaceManager::GetInterfaces when no MBN device exists

Tags: c#, com-interop, mobile-broadband-api

I have the following code working in Windows 7:

```
            MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
            IMbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgrInterface = mbnInfMgr as IMbnInterfaceManager;

            if (mbnInfMgrInterface != null)
            {
                IMbnInterface[] mobileInterfaces = mbnInfMgrInterface.GetInterfaces() as IMbnInterface[];
            }
```

No problems when the MBN device exists but when an MBN device doesn't exist I get the following exception in the call to GetInterfaces():

{System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070490): Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)
   at MbnApi.IMbnInterfaceManager.GetInterfaces()
   at foo.Program.configureConnection() in foo}

**Question**
Is there something that should be done to check for a MBN interface before calling GetInterfaces?  I can simply catch this exception but I can't find any documentation that says this exception is the same as having no interfaces.

The closest thing I have found on statckoverflow is this
[struggling with mobile broadband api windows 7 and windows 8 with C#, not sure what to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377811/struggling-with-mobile-broadband-api-windows-7-and-windows-8-with-c-not-sure-w)
which implies that maybe windows 7 behaves differently than windows 8.1.

Comment: I've noticed this happens on some cellular modem hardware if some of the "devices" in the device manager sense are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same `Element not found` exception trying to use GetSignalStrength() and MbnInterfaceManager I instead found you can obtain a lot of useful info using WMI.  Please see the answer here using `SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface`:

[struggling with mobile broadband api windows 7 and windows 8 with C#, not sure what to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21377811/struggling-with-mobile-broadband-api-windows-7-and-windows-8-with-c-not-sure-w/43058221#43058221)

**UPDATE:**

Please note that I found you cannot get the network info in Windows 8.1 in the same way as you do in Windows 7. See [How can I install an application that requires WMI capabilities on Windows 8.1 to determine available bandwidth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43081953/how-can-i-install-an-application-that-requires-wmi-capabilities-on-windows-8-1-t/43084135#43084135) and https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/network-information-sample-63aaa201