# How can I determine bandwidth on Windows 7, 8.1 and 10?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-8.1, wmi, clickonce

So far I have struggled to get `MbnInterfaceManager` working (see [hresult from IMbnInterfaceManager::GetInterfaces when no MBN device exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065362/hresult-from-imbninterfacemanagergetinterfaces-when-no-mbn-device-exists)), so instead I built and debugged an application with no problems from within Visual Studio 2015 that executed this WMI query in C# (see also the [`Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394293(VS.85).aspx)):

```cs
string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface";
ManagementObjectSearcher moSearch = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
ManagementObjectCollection moCollection = moSearch.Get();
```

But then when I deployed the application to Windows 8.1, I receive this error every time the query is executed:

```
System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid query 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?  How can I deploy an application so that it is able to use queries like this?

**UPDATE:**

Please note that I can build and run the above code (as part of a larger WPF application) from within Visual Studio 2015 on either Windows 7 or Windows 8.1, and I can deploy the same application using ClickOnce onto Windows 7 where it runs successfully.  For some reason when I deploy this application using ClickOnce  onto Windows 8.1, I get that `Invalid query` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I have to do is make sure that the `System.Management` reference is set to "Copy Local" but I'm not able to test that right now.  If anyone has any better ideas please feel free to let me know.

**UPDATE:**

It is not possible to use System.Management.dll on Windows 8.1 in the same way it is used on Windows 7 or Windows 10.

I've found that to perform operations similar to the ones I mentioned in my question on Windows 8.1 and Windows 8 phone you need to either get a Windows 8.1 developer license or on Windows 10 set your computer to "Developer Mode" so you can use the `Windows.Networking.Connectivity` namespace:

```
            string connectionProfileInfo = string.Empty;
            ConnectionProfile InternetConnectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

            if (InternetConnectionProfile == null)
            {
                rootPage.NotifyUser("Not connected to Internet\n", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                connectionProfileInfo = GetConnectionProfile(InternetConnectionProfile);
                OutputText.Text = connectionProfileInfo;
                rootPage.NotifyUser("Success", NotifyType.StatusMessage);
            }

            // Which calls this function, that allows you to determine how strong the signal is and the associated bandwidth
            string GetConnectionProfile(ConnectionProfile connectionProfile)
            {
                // ...
                    if (connectionProfile.GetSignalBars().HasValue)
                    {
                        connectionProfileInfo += "====================\n";
                        connectionProfileInfo += "Signal Bars: " + connectionProfile.GetSignalBars() + "\n";
                    }
                // ...
            }
```

Please note that you have to make sure your project is either a Window 8.1 PCL or a Windows 8.1 app to be able to reference the namespace.

For details please see https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/network-information-sample-63aaa201

**UPDATE 2:**

To be able to get bandwidth on Windows 7, 8.1 and 10, I ended up using this code:

```
    private int GetMaxBandwidth()
    {
        int maxBandwidth = 0;
        NetworkInterface[] networkIntrInterfaces  = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (var networkInterface in networkIntrInterfaces)
        {
            IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = networkInterface.GetIPv4Statistics();
            int bytesSentSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesSent);
            int bytesReceivedSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesReceived);

            if (bytesSentSpeed + bytesReceivedSpeed > maxBandwidth)
            {
                maxBandwidth = bytesSentSpeed + bytesReceivedSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
```